# NtSetInformationFile(..., FileBasicInformation) fails with STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER on FAT shares

Tags: winapi, driver, windows-kernel, nt-native-api

Stumbled upon a weird problem:

- let's say we have an SMB share `\\<server>\<share>` and we opened it for writing
- `NtSetInformationFile(..., FileBasicInformation)` normally succeeds
- ... but if underlying filesystem is FAT -- it fails with `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` (even if `FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure is zeroed out)

Why it fails and how to deal with this correctly?

Notes:

- share is on Windows Server 2012 R2 x64
- client is Win7 x64

*** More info ***

Converting to Win32 API `SetFileInformationByHandle()` didn't help -- it fails and yet `GetLastError()` returns `0`. Also, `SetFileTime()` and `SetFileAttributes()` calls fail with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

I guess, I need to somehow figure out if given path points to a share on FAT filesystem and silently skip metadata-related calls...

*** Code to reproduce ***

```
    TCHAR path[] = _T(R"(\\<server>\<share>)");

    DWORD dwAccess = GENERIC_WRITE|FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES|FILE_WRITE_EA; // 0x40000110
    HANDLE h = CreateFile(path, dwAccess, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
    DWORD err = GetLastError();

    IO_STATUS_BLOCK io = {};
    FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION bi = {};
    NTSTATUS s = NtSetInformationFile(h, &io, &bi, sizeof(bi), FileBasicInformation);

    printf("Result: 0x%08X\n", s);
```

Comment: When you say FAT, do you mean FAT16, FAT32, or exFAT? Are you observing this problem just on the mountpoint "//server/share"? Or also on files and subfolders? If it's just on the mountpoint, did you try adding a trailing slash, e.g. `"\\\\server\\share\\"`? Is the same problem reproducible with a local share? Or is it only with remote shares? I haven't been able to reproduce the problem in Windows 10 with a local share mountpoint for a directory on a local FAT32 filesystem.

Comment: @ErykSun FAT32 (`GetVolumeInformation()` returns `FAT`), Problem observed only on mount point, adding slash has no effect. I'll check local share asap. I added code to reproduce.

Comment: @ErykSun Works fine with local share (FAT and FAT32). Note: client is Win7 x64. But with remote share it fails with various clients (Win2012 included).

Comment: I tried again, this time with a share on a remote FAT (i.e. FAT16) filesystem, but still couldn't reproduce the issue between Windows 10 workstations. I suppose it's a bug with the SMB server in Windows Server 2012 R2. Anyway, if it fails as an invalid parameter, use the handle to query the filesystem via [`GetVolumeInformationByHandleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationbyhandlew), and address the "FAT" case in some way. Maybe log a warning about using the ancient FAT filesystem from the 1980s, instead of at least FAT32.

Comment: BTW, the filesystem name for FAT32 is "FAT32", not "FAT". If it says "FAT", then it's ancient FAT16.

Comment: @ErykSun I formatted my partition as FAT32, still `GetVolumeInformation` returns `FAT`. Yes, I guess I'll have to make a special case for `FAT`.

Comment: Sorry, apparently Server 2008 doesn't differentiate "FAT" from "FAT32" in the `FileFsAttributeInformation`. I know this used to be the case back in NT 4, but I thought it was changed in NT 6.x. In Windows 10 it does differentiate, which you can see in the published fastfat driver routine [`FatQueryFsAttributeInfo`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/325b87cf839b1b5c0ff46bb8c201612cfaedc561/filesys/fastfat/volinfo.c#L802).